# Mongoose isDeleted type interference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I have implemented soft-delete feature within my MongoDB collections. Now I have problems when I want to update mongoose library version from 4 to 5. The problem is that version 5.x.y of mongoose library supports soft-delete feature on its own (having `isDeleted()` method) which interferes with my own `isDeleted` field.

I have something like this:

```
export class Factory<E> {
  private readonly _model: Model<Document & E>;

  public get model(): Model<Document & E> {
    return this._model;
  }

  constructor(config: IFactoryConfiguration) {
    // ...
    let schema: Schema = new Schema(this.definition);
    this._model = this.connection.model<Document & E>(this.name, schema);
  }
}
```

Then I have:

```
export class UserFactory extends Factory<IUser> {
  constructor(connection: Connection) {
    super({
      connection: connection,
      name: 'User',
      definition: UserSchema
    });
  }
}
```

And:

```
export const UserSchema: SchemaDefinition = {
  // ...
  isDeleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  } // ...
}
```

`IUser` has `isDeleted: boolean;` property among others.

Now, I want to create/update system user every time a server is started:

```
let system = await this.factories.user.model.findOne({
  'isSystem': true
});

if (!system) {
  system = new this.factories.user.model();
  system.isSystem = true;
  system.isDeleted = true; <-- error here
  await system.save();
}
```

The problem is that I have `isDeleted` property inside my collection model (in this case `IUser`), but mongoose has `isDeleted()` method inside it's `Document` class. Since I have an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of `Document & IUser`, I'm getting some interference here. The error I'm getting is:

> Error:(239, 7) TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type '({ (isDeleted: boolean): void; (): boolean; } & false) | ({ (isDeleted: boolean): void; (): boolean; } & true)'.

Because there is `isDeleted(): boolean;` method (take a look [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/73241cf7f67a5c9253700756a94680397ad3ceef/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L3202)). How can I solve this issue?

Specifically, I want to update from

```
"mongoose": "^4.13.17",
"@types/mongoose": "^4.7.23",
```

to

```
"mongoose": "^5.4.7",
"@types/mongoose": "^5.3.10",
```

I'm using

```
"typescript": "^3.2.2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try with explicit casting when setting the `isDeleted`.

Something like:

```
<IUser>system.isDeleted = true
```

Comment: Great, this works! It was obvious that I should've cast it, but I didn't thought of doing so. One small note: proper syntax would be: `(<IUser>system).isDeleted = true;`.